# htmlunit can't click a button inside a table element

Tags: java, html, eclipse, selenium, htmlunit

I'm trying to click on the search button in this site: http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/portals/trek/default.aspx?Culture=en-US

But it apparently can't click it because the returned page is the same as the old page. It needs to return a page where the results of this search is displayed.

I tried htmlunitscripter but it does not seem to know that I clicked on the button and it doesn't generate the code for it. I tried :

```
HtmlElement theElement5 = (HtmlElement) page.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch");
page = (HtmlPage) theElement5.click();
```

But it doesn't work (returns the old page). I tried this next code in selenium and it worked but I can't use selenium because of the problems it caused when I tried to use it in a web service.

```
WebElement searchbutton = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch"));
searchbutton.click();
```

How can I reach this button in htmlunit? I didn't try xpath because I don't know how to get an element with it. Can someone please take a look at the site and propose a solution for reaching and clicking this button?

EDIT:

When I tried this one

```
page.executeJavaScript("var elem = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch'); elem.click();");
```

It throws this exception.

```
May 29, 2013 8:23:41 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine handleJavaScriptException
INFO: Caught script exception
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[1] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[injected script] message=[TypeError: Cannot find function click in object [object HTMLSpanElement]. (injected script#1)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function click in object [object HTMLSpanElement]. (injected script#1)
at        com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:555)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:530)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:979)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScript(HtmlPage.java:947)
at eko.htmlunit.ekoht.main(ekoht.java:63)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function click in object [object HTMLSpanElement]. (injected script#1)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3624)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3688)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2207)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2189)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1333)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:275)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:546)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:654)
... 7 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function click in object [object HTMLSpanElement]. (injected script#1)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3624)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3688)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2207)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2189)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1333)
at script(injected script:1)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:275)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:546)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:654)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:555)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:530)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:979)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScript(HtmlPage.java:947)
at eko.htmlunit.ekoht.main(ekoht.java:63)
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Apparently it can't find a click function for the element. What else could be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try executing the call via js to see if it works that way:

JS should be something like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch'); elem.click();
```

Comment: It throws an exception. I added the exception to the question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: I just noticed that you are using HtmlElement in your OP.  Have you tried HtmlSpan instead?  If that doesnt work I'd look into htmlunit capabilities to click span tags.

Comment: It didn't make a difference. The old page is returned again.

Comment: I also tried changing the elem.click() to elem.onclick() and the id to ...btnSearch_Table but it said this: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "cancelBubble" from undefined (http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/Amadeus/js/Functions.js#64)